# Combine multiple rows based on first column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 4,000 rows formatted with the seven columns below. I want to key off of the first column and combine all of the matching rows. So, for the first two rows below, they would merge to one row with C2&C3, F2&F3, and G2&G3 in a single cell in their respective columns. **For example:**

I would like the merged rows to look like this:

```
8876    AIX 1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2 Oracle 11.2.0.3.15 Purple,Blue Jim Smith,Bob Guy
```

Original table looks like this:

```
8876    AIX 1.1.1.1 Oracle  11.2.0.3.15 Purple  Jim Smith
8876    AIX 2.2.2.2 Oracle  11.2.0.3.15 Blue    Bob Guy
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I understand. Where should your output go? Should it replace the existing records, or should it go to another sheet?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  This is not a free code-writing service, but we would be happy to help you with code you are trying to develop.  Please post what you have accomplished and where you have run into trouble.  Also see the HELP section for information on how to post a good question.

Comment: @Bas Verlaat - yes, just replacing the multiple lines with the single line is the goal. thanks.

Comment: One more question. In your table example, there are blank lines between the groups of keys. Is that always the case, sometimes, or not at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Public Sub StartMerge()

    MergeRecords ActiveSheet.Range("$A$10:$H$19")

End Sub

Public Sub MergeRecords(rInputRange As Range, Optional sDelimiter As String = ",")

    Dim oRow        As Range
    Dim sPrevKey    As String
    Dim oPrevRow    As Range
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim j           As Long
    Dim bLoop       As Boolean
    Dim lRowIndex   As Long
    Dim aItems()    As String

    bLoop = True
    lRowIndex = 1

    Do While bLoop
        Set oRow = rInputRange.Rows(lRowIndex)
        If oRow.Cells(1) = sPrevKey Then
            For i = 2 To oRow.Cells.Count
                If InStr(oRow.Cells(i), sDelimiter) <> 0 Then
                    aItems = Split(oRow.Cells(i), sDelimiter)
                    For j = 0 To UBound(aItems)
                        If InStr(oPrevRow.Cells(i), aItems(j)) = 0 Then
                            oPrevRow.Cells(i) = oPrevRow.Cells(i) & "," & aItems(j)
                        End If
                    Next j
                Else
                    If InStr(oPrevRow.Cells(i), oRow.Cells(i)) = 0 Then
                        oPrevRow.Cells(i) = oPrevRow.Cells(i) & "," & oRow.Cells(i)
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            oRow.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
        Else
            Set oPrevRow = oRow
            sPrevKey = oRow.Cells(1)
            lRowIndex = lRowIndex + 1
        End If
        If lRowIndex > rInputRange.Rows.Count Then bLoop = False
    Loop

End Sub
```

Please make a backup first. It assumes that the first column contains the key

Comment: In his original data, one of the cells (third line, column F), had two codes separated by a comma.  One of those codes was a duplicate of the code in the first line (of the same ID in column A).  Given that data, your code would cause a duplicate in the output.

Comment: @Bas Verlaat - my VBA is very weak. How do i call the procedure when it requires arguments? The macro does not show up in the list, so i'm a bit confused on how to call it. In other words, how does "MergeRecords" get the required arguments? Thanks.

Comment: You can add a procedure that calls `MergeRecords` with arguments, which will be available in the list. I've amended the code. You could also use `selection` as the input range.

Comment: @BasVerlaat - Thanks so much for your help. It works well.